# Android Studio: how to wrap the long line of code (e.g. a long string) so that it fits the window

Tags: string, android-studio, coding-style

I've seen in a sample video that the code is wrapped and a little arrow is shown at the end of the line:[image]

How do you do that? `option + return` didn't help, also Googling yields nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Soft Wrap from Preferences. It shows up with code lines exceeding the window width.

[image]